# Can OPENROWSET authenticate with the signed in user running the query?

Tags: sql-server, openrowset, row-level-security, azure-analysis-services

My architecture is as follows:

1. On prem sql server database [Datawarehouse]
2. Azure Analysis Services Tabular model [Sales]
3. International report developers that query the [Datawarehouse] to develop reports*
4. RLS on tables in [Datawarehouse]
5. RLS on [Sales] tabular model

For testing that our data makes it correctly from [Datawarehouse] to [Sales] I would like to create a view on the [Datawarehouse] that uses OPENROWSET() to connect to the [Sales] tabular model. The only issue with this is I can see the user that runs the OPENROWSET() query on the [Sales] model is our sql admin user, not myself.

Is there a way to configure the OPENROWSET() so that the user that is executing the local query is also the user that executes the query on the linked server? As far as I can tell, passthrough credentials would be the best way to ensure proper security is maintained.

*the only reason I mention "international" is because the RLS is based on country

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want the credentials of the user who `SELECT`s from the View that's using `OPENROWSET()` to be propagated through the Linked Server, you just need to configure your Linked Server object's Security properties to "*be made using the login's current security context*":

[image: Linked Server]

This will respect Row-Level Security policies on the Linked Server's side.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I have two follow up questions. 1. I thought that openrowset() was in place of a linked server. Is this possible using just openrowset()? 2. When I attempt to setup the linked server as you described I get the error message "Errors in the OLE DB provider. Integrated Security must not be set or set to ClaimsToken or SSPI in order to access this server". Is SSPI the correct choice in this situation and if it is, where can I add that to the connection configuration?

Comment: @Antyan No,`OPENROWSET()` and `OPENQUERY()` still query via a Linked Server. The only difference is `OPENROWSET()` can also query additional data sources that are compatible with the ODBC protocol. I'm not super familiar with troubleshooting SSPI issues other than making sure your servers are configured to communicate with each other (this is more of a Network Admin question). I believe you have to make sure delegation and SPNs are properly setup. Please reference this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/cannot-generate-sspi-context-error) for more info.